# Php code to Generate Log File

Tags: php, logging, count

I want a php code which generate File log of accessing another php file
Like
a file in server as
example.com/file.php

I want a Date wise log in log.php
when any one access the file.php
Means Every time this file.php opens from any where it will count the number of times and generate the Log file Date wise count on Log.php

Thanks in Advance.

Output will be like this

```
8-sept-13 :- 5262
9-sept 13 :- 5555
```

and so on.
it will generate date wise log.

I Tryed This But its Just adding and counting the file access How to make this Date wise.

```
$filename = "logs.php";
$count= file($filename);
$count[0]++;
$file = fopen ($filename, "w") or die ("Cannot find $filename");
fputs($file, "$count[0]");
fclose($file);
```

Comment: What do you have tried so far?

Comment: I Have updated my Question which i have tryed.! How to make that script Date wise.?

Comment: in `9-sept 13 :- 5555`  what is `5555`?

Comment: Its the Number of file open count. How many times the file open every time it will update it its a simple example. the count will start from 0 every day and will show day wise counting of opening of a php file.

Comment: So basically you just want date (and time?) and visit count?

Comment: I Just Want Date not time. Means Date wise count only. Means for one day one line log with all total count on that like as shown in Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $filename = "logs.php";
    $lines = file($filename);
    if(count($lines)!=0){
        $data  = explode( " :- ", $lines[count($lines) -1 ]);
        if(date('d-M-y')   ==  $data[0]){
            $data[1]++;
            $lines[count($lines) -1 ] = $data[0].' :- '. $data[1];
        }else{
            $lines[] = date('d-M-y').' :- 1';
        }

    }else{
        echo 'Empty';
        $lines[] = date('d-M-y').' :- 1';
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, implode("\n", $lines ) );

?>
```

Comment: Thankx But its providing outpout as 08-Sep-13 :- 4 09-Sep-13 :- 4  How to make that Per Line. i am unable to add <br/> to make that per line.

Comment: use `nl2br` function!

Comment: Can you provide me line where i will add this.!! as i am new in PHP :)

Comment: create another file :`<?php  echo '<pre>';include($filename);echo '</pre>'; ?>`